# How to fix a possible power surge on the usb port? (power surge protection reset)

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, motherboard, bios, surge-protection

Can't start the computer at all, and the problem occured possibly due to a voltage fluctuation caused by a wifi adapter. Checked for anything that could short-circuit or intervene the mobo from working correctly, unluckily found nothing.

While starting up the computer, even before I could enter into BIOS, i get the error message: 'USB device over current status detected will shut down in 15 seconds', and it shuts down. The problem as I mentioned, occured due to using a usb Wi-fi adapter. edit: it was plugged into the back of the computer, no hubs used meanwhile.

BIOS has been reseted already(cmos battery removal, clear jumper, check ports' connections on the mobo for signs of deformation or defunction, front usb control cable removal, check if anything else could be intervening, undusting), but i get the same error message.
I can't enter into BIOS, so there's no chance to disable anything from there.

The faulty adapter has been since removed, and I wouldn't want to really use it in the future, just want to make my mobo to work again. (sidenote: even pondering to desolder the usb ports, but unsure if it would do the trick) Now I am trying to gather more knowledge about power surge protection and its reseting. Any advices or ideas if it's the right approach?

The motherboard specs: msi z270 gaming m7
(seems unrelevant, but OS is: windows 10)

Comment: Certainly unplug all devices you can, make sure the computer is fully off (unplug it from AC), leave off for 5 minutes, and then attempt to restart. If the USB Socket was electrically damaged under power, the motherboard may itself be damaged or need repair.  Surge protection is helpful. I use a proper UPS.

Comment: On reddit there is a discussion about USB ports and fuses. In a linked article it say that the self-healing of such a fuse can take multiple days:  https://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/comments/1vkvdb/does_usb_port_have_a_fuse/

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Special thanks to Robert for the link, I will try to let the fuse cool.

Comment: Some latch-up happens on overcurrent input. Try to power everything off, disconnect from AC, remove CMOS (3V Li-ion) battery, wait ~10 minutes, short on-board battery terminals directly. Then put back the battery and power the system, And pray...